# Bash script to email when wc -l count is below 3

Tags: linux, bash, unix, wc

Please, can you help me with a script that counts something (wc -l) and when the count is below 3 the script emails me.

Thank you!

Comment: what did you try so far? As a start: ```X=`wc -l something`; if [ $X -lt 3 ]; then : do something; fi;```

Comment: I have a folder with 26 files. If the count files is below 3 then email me. So the command is ls |wc -l and this command is returning 26 and after that?

Comment: OK, write something like ```X=`ls -1 | wc -l`; ``` Then you can test the value of X as above. Still it would greatly enhance the acceptance of your question if you'd show what you tried so far.

Comment: I think I will try with If <3 then mailto... Thank you!

Comment: @Ronald Please don't advocate deprecated syntax like backticks; use `$()` for command substitution.

Comment: What is the definition of `something` in your vocabulary?

Comment: @4ae1e1 Well, I personally prefer to use backticks because that works in any bourne alike shell. Your comment is valid nevertheless, because the question has been tagged with "bash". Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[ $( find /folder/with/files -type f | wc -l ) -lt 3 ]] && mail -t someone@somewhere.com -s Problem <<< "Less than three files."
```

`Find` and `wc -l` return the count of files and then `[[` evaluates if the count is lees than three. If this evaluates to true and returns zero exit status, next command after `&&` is executed.

If the mail environment is set up correctly, mail with given subject and message will be sent.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
num=`ls |wc -l`
#echo $num
if [ "$num" -lt "4" ]
then echo "Pam,pam"
fi